# Compiling reverse geocoding in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c

I'm writing a program for iOS 5.  The program should perform reverse geocoding.

When trying to compile I get the warning

> MKReverseGeocoder is deprecated

and an error

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in UserLocationAddressViewController.o"

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I compile without the warning and the error?
2. I want the application to run on iOS 3, iOS 4, and on iOS 5. How can I do it?

Comment: Did I answer your question? If not, please let me know so I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your deployment target is set to the lowest iOS version you want to support. In the example below, the app is built for 5.0 (base SDK), but will run on iOS 4.0 (deployment target):

[image]

[image]

Setting this to any value below 5.0 will remove the deprecation warning.